# How can I check a parameter is passed in in jade template

Tags: parameters, pug

I want render a `jade` template:

```
res.render('tmp.jade')
```

In my template, I want judge if pass a parameter in first, just like in javasript:

```
- if (temp) {
   - for (var key in temp) {

   - }
- }
```

but this is wrong, the `temp` is not defined

How can check the parameter pass in first?

Comment: you want to check in the template whether the variable is assigned a value? or you want to test before the call to render that tmep has a value?

Comment: @0xor1: I want check in the jade file, not before the render, in the render

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
temp = {foo:"bar"}
each val, key in temp
    li #{key}: #{val}
```

From [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a9), assuming you want to create a list of the keys and their values. but you could replace that with whatever you want.

presumabley if `temp` was undefined it would have nothing to iterate over.